# Error starting WebLogic server from NetBeans

Tags: weblogic

I  try to start Oracle Weblogic Server from within Netbeans and I am  getting the error:

```
**Stopping Weblogic Server...

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Connecting to t3://localhost:7001 with userid weblogic ...
This Exception occurred at Wed Oct 23 15:51:17 CEST 2013.
javax.naming.AuthenticationException [Root exception is java.lang.SecurityException: User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated.]
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/nasimjon/Downloads/wls12120/user_projects/domains/mydomain/shutdown.py", line 3, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 19, in connect
  File "<iostream>", line 520, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated. 
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :

Done
Stopping Derby Server...
**

Oracle Weblogic server stop field:
```

Can anyone find solution on web? If yes just put link.

Comment: I don't know WebLogic, but I were you I'd investigate the root cause of this: "*User: weblogic, failed to be authenticated*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLST can't authenticate for some reason to the weblogic server. Have you changed how the authentication works? Or removed the weblogic user from the security realm? You probably need to check what is being called to shutdown weblogic (normally a script stopWeblogic.sh/.cmd is called), and does the original script still work? If stopWeblogic works, the problem is in NetBeans calling it's own script, if not then you have probably changed something in weblogic.